# How can I highlight library classes differently in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, highlight, semantics

I'm trying to configure IntelliJ Idea to highlight classes from the current project and classes from libraries/JDK differently. That would help to easily understand origin of all these classes like `Transaction`, `Request`, `Query`, `Column`. Also, during debugging, it would allow to step only into lines with code from project (it is usually much more buggy and suspicious).

Yes, I know about `Ctrl+hover on symbol`/ `Ctrl+Q` / `Smart step into`. But visual indication may be much easier to recognize.

Is there a way to get that (maybe with some plugin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be exactly what you're asking but it's very similar and could help with differentiating library and project files.

- Project Files - that's your source code, etc
- Non-Project Files - files that are from Jar files

[image: Appearance & Behavior > File Colors]

Comment: Yes, that is close. Thanks. Maybe somebody will post some workaround for in-text highlighting.